# ng-hide is not hiding a empty value

Tags: angularjs

**Problem:** I am trying to hide a value if the distance is empty/null.

I tried the following and the value is still appearing:

```
<div ng-hide="e.distance == null"><strong>Distance: </strong>{{e.distance}}</div><br />
```

and

```
<div ng-show="e.distance != null"><strong>Distance: </strong>{{e.distance}}</div><br />
```

What is the right approach to achieve what I am looking.

Here is how I define distance in coldfusion:

```
<cfif isdefined("Distance")>
        <cfset qDistance="#Distance#">
    <cfelse>
        <cfset qDistance="5">
    </cfif>   

DECLARE @lat float
        , @lon float
        , @dist int = <cfqueryparam value = "#qDistance#" cfsqltype = "cf_sql_integer">
```

When I do the following suggestion:

ng-show="e.distance === undefined"

shows the following: [image: click on image]

when I do the other suggestion, example ng-hide="e.distance",

It just shows the following:
[image]

Here is what the Provider contains:

```
indexApp.controller('IndexController',function($scope,$http,$location,anchorSmoothScroll){
    $scope.Lang = 'initVal';
    $scope.ShowResults = false;
    $scope.ShowDesc = true;
    $scope.NoResults = false;
    $scope.currentPage = 1;
    $scope.maxPageNumbersToShow = 10;
    $scope.formModel = {};
    $scope.searchMode = 0;
    $scope.miles =  [{'value':'5'},{'value':'10'},{'value':'15'},{'value':'20' }];
    $scope.Specialties = [{'value':'Family practice'},{'value':'General practice'},{'value':'Internal medicine'},{'value':'Pediatrics'}];
    $scope.Gender = [{'value':'Male'},{'value':'Female'}];
    $scope.Languages = {};
    $scope.Cities = {};
    $scope.searchParam = {};
    $("input").removeAttr('disabled');

    $scope.searchParam.Distance = $scope.miles[0];
```

Comment: what is the value of e.distance? what does it prints?

Comment: @firegloves: it shows blank but their is a space in the value

Comment: with blank you mean empty string? try putting some chars before and after printed value please

Comment: Then it's not null. How about `ng-show="e.distance"` which shows if distance is truthy (i.e. null, undefined, empty string, 0, or true)

Comment: @firegloves: I did, I entered "0" and it shows the value next to the distance. However, their is a space and I replaced the null with a space and it still appears

Comment: @Robert post your new code please and try JB Nizet solution, even if I believe that it should be at least ng-hide="! e.distance", right JB?

Comment: @Robert this is very unclear. Post an example containing the JS code that defines e.distance.

Comment: @firegloves right. Or better, to avoid the double nagation: `ng-show="e.distance"`.

Comment: @JBNizet I have added what you have requested and in the database, if distance is blank, it will appear blank

Comment: No, you haven't. There is 0 JavaScript code in your question.

Comment: @Robert post something like ###{{ e.distance }]*** prints ### *** or whatever it prints. so we can understand what is happening

Comment: ok so what contains e object? XD

Comment: @firegloves I have posted what I am seeing

Comment: Do you know that you are doing? I think no. We are asking you to see what contains your named e object. So if you can post what we asked you we can help you, otherwise it should be better you go to review angular documentation

Comment: @firegloves: it is  ng-repeat="e in providers"

Comment: @Robert e is an object of the array providers. an object has a structure, some data, some fields...what contains your e object? more precisely what contains the e object that cause you problems?

Comment: @firegloves Thank you for the explanation

Comment: @Robert you are too too too confused. Right now it's impossible to help you. I renew my invita to review AngularJS docs and to spend some time to understand imperative coding paradigm

Comment: @firegloves okay thank you

Comment: Please use ng-hide="!e.distance"

Comment: @firegloves: nvm I saw what I did wrong. Thanks for you help. I was confused myself on what I wanted but I fixed it. Sorry for the hassle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use like this:

```
<div ng-show="e.distance"><strong>Distance: </strong>{{e.distance}}</div><br />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using ng-if instead of ng-show and to check variable like this:

```
<div ng-if="e.distance"><strong>Distance: </strong>{{e.distance}}</div><br />
```